# TIdTCPServer OnExecute runs in an infinite loop

Tags: delphi, indy

I am having a problem with the `TIdTCPServer` component. I use it to read data sent by remote server.

Below is the code I use:

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
const
  START_PACKET = #11;
  END_PACKET = #10;
var
  IO : TIdIOHandler;
  c  : Char;
  a  : AnsiString;
begin
  a := '';
  IO := AContext.Connection.IOHandler;

  while (IO.InputBuffer.Size > 0) do
  begin
    c := IO.ReadChar;

    if c = START_PACKET then
    begin
      repeat
        c := IO.ReadChar; //(TEncoding.ASCII);
        a := a + c;
      until (c = END_PACKET) or (IO.InputBufferIsEmpty);
    end;
  end;

  if a <> '' then
  begin
    //let's send replay to server
    IO.Write(CreateReply(a));

    //now we need to save what we received to database
    //I use critical section
    try
      EnterCriticalSection(LockDB);

      with DataModule2.results do
      begin
        Close;
        Params[0].AsDateTime := Today;
        Params[1].AsString := a;
        ExecSQL;
      end;
    finally
      LeaveCriticalSection(LockDB);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The problem is that once my `TIdTCPServer` gets some data it starts an infinite loop and takes 100% of CPU.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that you are never actually reading any data, so the `InputBuffer` will always be empty and `a` will thus always be blank.  The `OnExecute` event itself is looped, so you are not doing anything to make it yield CPU time slices periodically.

Another problem is that your char-by-char reading and concatenation is very inefficient, and it doesn't take into account that `SizeOf(Char)` is 2 in Delphi 2009+ or that `ReadChar()` is Unicode-aware.

Try this instead:

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
const
  START_PACKET = #11;
  END_PACKET = #10;
var
  IO : TIdIOHandler;
  a, buf : AnsiString;
  buflen : Integer;
  c : AnsiChar;
begin
  a := '';
  IO := AContext.Connection.IOHandler;

  IO.WaitFor(START_PACKET);

  // this is just one example of how to append characters using
  // buffering. use whatever is more comfortable for you...

  SetLength(buf, 1024);
  buflen := 0;

  repeat
    c := AnsiChar(IO.ReadByte);
    if buflen = Length(buf) then
    begin
      a := a + buf;
      buflen := 0;
    end;
    buf[buflen+1] := c;
    Inc(buflen);
  until (c = END_PACKET) or (IO.InputBufferIsEmpty);

  if buflen > 0 then
  begin
    SetLength(buf, buflen);
    a := a + buf;
  end;
  buf := '';

  //let's send replay to server
  IO.Write(CreateReply(a));

  //now we need to save what we received to database
  //I use critical section
  EnterCriticalSection(LockDB);
  try
    with DataModule2.results do
    begin
      Close;
      Params[0].AsDateTime := Today;
      Params[1].AsString := a;
      ExecSQL;
    end;
  finally
    LeaveCriticalSection(LockDB);
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
const
  START_PACKET = #11;
  END_PACKET = $#10;
var
  IO : TIdIOHandler;
  a : AnsiString;
  c : AnsiChar;
  i : Integer;
begin
  IO := AContext.Connection.IOHandler;

  IO.WaitFor(START_PACKET);

  if IO.InputBufferIsEmpty then
  begin
    IO.CheckForDataOnSource(IdTimeoutDefault);
    IO.CheckForDisconnect;
  end;

  i := IO.InputBuffer.IndexOf(END_PACKET);
  if i = -1 then i := IO.InputBuffer.Size;

  a := IO.ReadString(i);

  if a <> '' then
  begin
    //let's send replay to server
    IO.Write(CreateReply(a));

    //now we need to save what we received to database
    //I use critical section
    EnterCriticalSection(LockDB);
    try
      with DataModule2.results do
      begin
        Close;
        Params[0].AsDateTime := Today;
        Params[1].AsString := a;
        ExecSQL;
      end;
    finally
      LeaveCriticalSection(LockDB);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: `pkt := IO.ReadLn(END_PACKET, Indy8BitEncoding) + END_PACKET;` will it read all pocket from server? I am using D7 with 'indy10.1.5_d7' which I believe does not have ReadLn(END_PACKET, Indy8BitEncoding), what should I do in this situation? Is it ok to use just IO.ReadLn?

Comment: `ReadLn()` reads until the specified terminator arrives, then it returns everything that is prior to the terminator and discards the terminator itself. Your original code was preserving the terminator in your `AnsiString`, hense the `+ END_PACKET` portion in my example. Whether you really need to preserve the terminator is up to you. As for Indy 10.1.5, it did not support Unicode yet, so just omit the `Indy8BitEncoding` portion but still pass the `END_PACKET` terminator to `ReadLn()`. Or upgrade to the latest 10.6.0 version (which you should consider doing anything since 10.1.5 is VERY old).

Comment: The program never pass this line of code: `pkt := IO.ReadLn(END_PACKET) + END_PACKET;` as if `END_PACKET` never appear.

Comment: If `ReadLn()` is never exiting then either the terminator is never being received at all (use a packet sniffer, such as WireShark, to check that) or you have another thread reading from the same IOHandler àt the same time and eating the terminator that `ReadLn()` is waiting for.

Comment: I am looking at newest Indy and I can see that you are the author of the newest Indy! Lots of respect to you Remy!

Comment: My `IdTCPServer` `MaxConnections` is set to 0. Does it guarantee that there is only one thread reading from the same IOHandler? My previous solution was using: `until (c = END_PACKET) or (IO.InputBufferIsEmpty);` so the loop finishes when we get `END_PACKET` or `IO.InputBufferIsEmpty`... how can I re-create this functionality in more clever way?

Comment: `MaxConnections=0` means there is no limit. The server will keep accepting clients as long as available resources allow it. That has nothing to do with how you code your `IOHandler` access. The only reason to check `InputBufferIsEmpty` is if not every packet ends with `END_PACKET` and you have no other way of knowing (such as by analyzing the packet content) which packet will end with `END_PACKET` and which will not. If that is actually the case, then the protocol is not very well designed.

Comment: Can I use `ReadLn` or another function to take into consideration that not every packet ends with `END_PACKET`?

Comment: `ReadLn()` does not support that. You will have to resort to using `InputBufferIsEmpty()` again, or use `InputBuffer.IndexOf()`.  I have updated my answer with examples of both.